# Break promise chain when condition is not met

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Hi I'm trying to do a simple thing, when a condition is not met don't go to the 3rd then. I know I can stop by placing a break statement to throw an error but is not the proper way to handle this, so I tried to call another function from outside to stop there without success:

```js
Promise.resolve("hello")
.then((value)=> { return value})
.then(param=> {
 if(typeof(param) === "number"){
   console.log(param)
    return
  }else{
   console.log("I'll be stuck here")
    return outside()
  }
})

.then(()=>{
 console.log("inside 3rd promise")
})

function outside(){
 console.log("I'm outside")
  
}
```

Comment: A `break` statement? What book are you reading? I might go back and re-read some basic JS tutorials. A function call is not a **GOTO** statement or a `longjmp`.

Comment: I didn't find the above link answering the same question, sorry

Comment: Just `throw` an exception ;) It is basically the only way, it would then continue to the first coming catch statement (and then potentially continue with the `then` statements following the `catch` block)